# Are infinite lists useful for any real world applications?

Tags: list, haskell, lazy-evaluation, infinite

I've been using haskell for quite a while now, and I've read most of Real World Haskell and Learn You a Haskell. What I want to know is whether there is a point to a language using lazy evaluation, in particular the "advantage" of having infinite lists, is there a task which infinite lists make very easy, or even a task that is only possible with infinite lists?

Comment: If you consider a blogging web application a 'real world applications', you probably don't need infinite lists. But as SK-Logic is pointing out it's quite handy for the more 'advanced' stuff like building a lexer/parser.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here's an utterly trivial but actually day-to-day useful example of where infinite lists specifically come in handy: When you have a list of items that you want to use to initialize some key-value-style data structure, starting with consecutive keys. So, say you have a list of strings and you want to put them into an `IntMap` counting from 0. Without lazy infinite lists, you'd do something like walk down the input list, keeping a running "next index" counter and building up the `IntMap` as you go.

With infinite lazy lists, the list itself takes the role of the running counter; just use `zip [0..]` with your list of items to assign the indices, then `IntMap.fromList` to construct the final result.

Sure, it's essentially the same thing in both cases. But having lazy infinite lists lets you express the concept much more directly without having to worry about details like the length of the input list or keeping track of an extra counter.

Answer (score 13):

An obvious example is chaining your data processing from input to whatever you want to do with it. E.g., reading a stream of characters into a lazy list, which is processed by a lexer, also producing a lazy list of tokens which are parsed into a lazy AST structure, then compiled and executed. It's like using Unix pipes.

Comment: Except that's not an infinite list, just a lazy list.

Comment: If you're reading from a socket or a pipe, it's technically infinite, if EOF is never read. Internal representation is similar - a tail is alway evaluated as a recursive function.

Answer (score 8):

I found it's often easier and cleaner to just define all of a sequence in one place, even if it's infinite, and have the code that uses it just grab what it wants.

```
take 10 mySequence
takeWhile (<100) mySequence
```

instead of having numerous similar but not quite the same functions that generate a subset

```
first10ofMySequence
elementsUnder100ofMySequence
```

The benefits are greater when different subsections of the same sequence are used in different areas.

Comment: This is the heart of it in my view. It's conceptually simpler and leads to cleaner code reuse.

Answer (score 7):

Infinite data structures (including lists) give a huge boost to modularity and hence reusability, as explained & illustrated in John Hughes's classic paper [*Why Functional Programming Matters*](http://www.cse.chalmers.se/~rjmh/Papers/whyfp.html).
For instance, you can decompose complex code chunks into producer/filter/consumer pieces, each of which is potentially useful elsewhere.

So wherever you see real-world value in code reuse, you'll have an answer to your question.

Answer (score 6):

Basically, lazy lists allow you to delay computation until you need it. This can prove useful when you don't know in advance when to stop, and what to precompute.

A standard example is u_n a sequence of numerical computations converging to some limit. You can ask for the first term such that |u_n - u_{n-1}| < epsilon, the right number of terms is computed for you.

Now, you have two such sequences u_n and v_n, and you want to know the sum of the limits to epsilon accuracy. The algorithm is:

- compute u_n until epsilon/2 accuracy
- compute v_n until epsilon/2 accuracy
- return u_n + v_n

All is done lazily, only the necessary u_n and v_n are computed. You may want less simple examples, eg. computing f(u_n) where you know (ie. know how to compute) f's modulus of continuity.

Answer (score 4):

Sound synthesis - see this paper by Jerzy Karczmarczuk:

http://users.info.unicaen.fr/~karczma/arpap/cleasyn.pdf

Jerzy Karczmarcuk has a number of other papers using infinite lists to model mathematical objects like power series and derivatives.

I've translated the basic sound synthesis code to Haskell - enough for a sine wave unit generator and WAV file IO. The performance was just about adequate to run with GHCi on a 1.5GHz Athalon - as I just wanted to test the concept I never got round to optimizing it.

Answer (score 3):

Infinite/lazy structures permit the idiom of "tying the knot": http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Tying_the_Knot

The canonically simple example of this is the Fibonacci sequence, defined directly as a recurrence relation. (Yes, yes, hold the efficiency complaints/algorithms discussion -- the point is the *idiom*.): `fibs = 1:1:zipwith (+) fibs (tail fibs)`

Here's another story. I had some code that only worked with finite streams -- it did some things to create them out to a point, then did a whole bunch of nonsense that involved acting on various bits of the stream dependent on the entire stream prior to that point, merging it with information from another stream, etc. It was pretty nice, but I realized it had a whole bunch of cruft necessary for dealing with boundary conditions, and basically what to do when one stream ran out of stuff. I then realized that conceptually, there was no reason it couldn't work on infinite streams. So I switched to a data type without a nil -- i.e. a genuine stream as opposed to a list, and all the cruft went away. Even though I know I'll never need the data past a certain point, being able to rely on it being there allowed me to safely remove lots of silly logic, and let the mathematical/algorithmic part of my code stand out more clearly.

Answer (score 3):

One of my pragmatic favorites is `cycle`. `cycle [False, True]` generates the infinite list `[False, True, False, True, False ...]`. In particular, `xs ! 0 = False`, `xs ! 1 = True`, so this is just says whether or not the index of the element is odd or not. Where does this show up? Lot's of places, but here's one that any web developer ought to be familiar with: making tables that alternate shading from row to row.

The general pattern seen here is that if we want to do some operation on a finite list, rather than having to construct a specific finite list that will “do the thing we want,” we can use an infinite list that will work for all sizes of lists. camcann’s answer is in this vein.